# How to solve docker container increasing RSS memory

Tags: linux, docker, memory-management, memory-leaks, containers

Here at work we have a C# service running in a docker container which is monitored on datadog. But of recent the container's RSS memory is on the increase more than 70% of the container's assigned memory which is 2gb. How do I resolve this spike. Do I kill restart the container? And what could be the possible reason for this spike.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your container:

```bash
docker run -it --memory=${MEMORY_LIMIT} ${IMAGE}
```

When having a running container:

```bash
LIMIT=1g #for example
docker update --memory "${LIMIT}" ${CONTAINER_ID}
```